# django-tastypie: linking a ModelResource to a Resource

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I'm currently trying django-tastypie to design a RESTful api. I'm facing a problem:

```
# the RevisionObject retrieve commits info through pysvn
# This Resource is fully functionnal (RevisionObject code is not here)
class RevisionResource(Resource):
    id = fields.CharField(attribute='revision')
    description = fields.CharField(attribute='message')
    author = fields.CharField(attribute='author')
    changed_path = fields.ListField(attribute='changed_paths')

    class Meta:
        object_class = RevisionObject
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'revision'

class RevisionToApplyResource(ModelResource):
    #### here's the problem
    revision = fields.ToManyField(RevisionResource, 'revision')
    ####
    class Meta:
        queryset = RevisionToApply.objects.all()
```

In my models.py I have:

```
class RevisionToApply(models.Model):
    patch = models.ForeignKey(PatchRequest)
    revision = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    applied = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

My problem is that the RevisionToApply models (for django) uses an int to the revision.

How can I tell tastypie to use the revision field of RevisionToApplyResource as a pointer to a RevisionResource? If the ToXxxxField are only for linking with django models, what is the perfect moment to insert the ResourceObject?

thanks.

```
class NoForeignKeyToOneField(ToOneField):
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        try:
            obj_key = getattr(bundle.obj, self.attribute)
            foreign_obj = self.to_class().obj_get(pk=obj_key)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            foreign_obj= None

        if not foreign_obj:
            if not self.null:
                raise ApiFieldError("The model '%r' has an empty attribute"
                   "'%s' and doesn't allow null value." % (bundle.obj,
                   self.attribute))
            return None

        self.fk_resource = self.get_related_resource(foreign_obj)
        fk_bundle = Bundle(obj=foreign_obj, request=bundle.request)
        return self.dehydrate_related(fk_bundle, self.fk_resource)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. Taking a look at how the `ToOneField` class works, you'll notice that the hydrate/dehydrate method pair takes care of getting and setting the actual related instance. By subclassing `ToOneField` and overriding these two methods, you can get the benefit of Tastypie's automated resource handling without an actual foreign key.

(I'm referring to `ToOneField` rather than `ToManyField` because in your model, a given `RevisionToApply` can only point to one revision, it seems.)

It would look something like this:

```py
class NoForeignKeyToOneField(ToOneField):

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        # Look up the related object manually
        try:
            obj_key = getattr(bundle.obj, self.attribute)
            ###
            # Get the revision object here. If you want to make it generic,
            # maybe pass a callable on __init__ that can be invoked here
            ###
            foreign_obj = revision_object
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            foreign_obj = None
        # The rest remains the same
        if not foreign_obj:
            if not self.null:
                raise ApiFieldError("The model '%r' has an empty attribute '%s' and doesn't allow a null value." % (bundle.obj, self.attribute))
            return None

        self.fk_resource = self.get_related_resource(foreign_obj)
        fk_bundle = Bundle(obj=foreign_obj, request=bundle.request)
        return self.dehydrate_related(fk_bundle, self.fk_resource)

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        value = super(NoForeignKeyToOneField, self).hydrate(bundle)

        if value is None:
            return value

        # Here, don't return the full resource, only the primary key
        related_resource = self.build_related_resource(value, request=bundle.request)
        return related_resource.pk
```

And then use this field type in your resource rather than the basic `ToOneField`. I haven't tested it , but I believe the approach is sound, simple and it'll get the job done.

Comment: It works for the dehydrate method. thank you for the tips. I'm still having trouble with the hydrate one.