# Tastypie - Linking to a "ForeignKey"

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have two legacy models listed below.  The `Library.libtype_id` is *effectively* a foreign key to LibraryType when libtype_id > 0.  I want to represent this as a ForeignKey Resource in TastyPie when that condition is met.

Can someone help me out?  I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672452/django-tastypie-linking-a-modelresource-to-a-resource) but I'm not sure it's the same thing? Thanks much!!

```
# models.py
class LibraryType(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=96)

class Library(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project = models.ForeignKey('project.Project', db_column='parent')
    libtype_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='libTypeId')
```

Here is my api.py

```
class LibraryTypeResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = LibraryType.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'library_type'

class LibraryResource(ModelResource):
    project = fields.ForeignKey(ProjectResource, 'project')
    libtype = fields.ForeignKey(LibraryTypeResource, 'libtype_id' )

    class Meta:
        queryset = Library.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'library'
        exclude = ['libtype_id']

    def dehydrate_libtype(self, bundle):
        if getattr(bundle.obj, 'libtype_id', None) != 0:
            return LibraryTypeResource.get_detail(id=bundle.obj.libtype_id)
```

When I do this however I'm getting the following error on `http://0.0.0.0:8001/api/v1/library/?format=json`

```
"error_message": "'long' object has no attribute 'pk'",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
libtype = fields.ForeignKey(LibraryTypeResource, 'libtype_id' )
```

be

```
libtype = fields.ForeignKey(LibraryTypeResource, 'libtype' )
```

(without the '_id')

I believe that as it is you are handing the field an `int` and it is attempting to get the `pk` from it.

**UPDATE**:

*Missed that `libtype_id` is an `IntegerField`, not a `ForeignKey` (whole point of the question)*

Personally I would add a method to the `Library` to retrieve the `LibraryType` object.  This way you have access to the `LibraryType` from the `Library` and you don't have to override any `dehydrate` methods.

```
class Library(models.Model):
    # ... other fields
    libtype_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='libTypeId')

    def get_libtype(self):
        return LibraryType.objects.get(id=self.libtype_id)
```

.

```
class LibraryResource(ModelResource):
    libtype = fields.ForeignKey(LibraryTypeResource, 'get_libtype')
```

Comment: That's a bit better.. but now I have an issue with my get_detail.  How should I reference that - I want the uri?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get you.  Do you need `dehydrate_libtype` at all?

Comment: How else is it correlated to a specific resource id?

Comment: `fields.ForeignKey` will return the uri to the related object.  if you add `full=True` then it will return the entire related object

Comment: Right - but what links the the `libtype_id` to that foreignkey when `libtype_id` > 0?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I missed that you had an `IntegerField` not a `ForeignKey`